# how i can créate Multiple keyName to the same section in file.ini?

Tags: c#, ini

```
     c#
     public static void FileIni(string file)
    {
        string username = Environment.UserName;
       Ini RCFile = new Ini(@"C:\SYS\PSA\Log" + "/BackupLite.INI");

        string Name = Path.GetFileName(file);
        switch (Name)
        {


            case "pv4printers.xml": RCFile.IniWriteValue("Imprimante", "Path", Path.GetFullPath(file)); break;
            case "StickyNotes.snt": RCFile.IniWriteValue("Sticky Notes", "Path", Path.GetFullPath(file)); break;
            case "notepad++": RCFile.IniWriteValue("Notepad++", "Path", Path.GetFullPath(file)); break;
            case "Bookmarks": RCFile.IniWriteValue("Favoris Chrome", "Path", Path.GetFullPath(file)); break;
            case "Favicons":RCFile.IniWriteValue("Favoris Chrome", "Path", Path.GetFullPath(file)); break;
            case "Network Action Predictors": RCFile.IniWriteValue("Favoris Chrome", "Path", Path.GetFullPath(file)); break;
            case "Favorites": RCFile.IniWriteValue("Favoris IE", "Path", Path.GetFullPath(file)); break;
            case "Network Shortcuts": RCFile.IniWriteValue("Network Shortcuts", "Path", Path.GetFullPath(file)); break;
            case "FileZilla": RCFile.IniWriteValue("Filezilla", "Path", Path.GetFullPath(file)); break;
            case "Proof": RCFile.IniWriteValue("Config Office", "Path", Path.GetFullPath(file)); break;
            case "XLSTART": RCFile.IniWriteValue("Config Office", "Path", Path.GetFullPath(file)); break;
            case "STARTUP": RCFile.IniWriteValue("Config Office", "Path", Path.GetFullPath(file)); break;
            case "Access": RCFile.IniWriteValue("Config Office", "Path", Path.GetFullPath(file)); break;
            case "UProof": RCFile.IniWriteValue("Config Office", "Path", Path.GetFullPath(file)); break;
            case "Templates": RCFile.IniWriteValue("Config Office", "Path", Path.GetFullPath(file)); break;
            case "Signatures": RCFile.IniWriteValue("Config Office", "Path", Path.GetFullPath(file)); break;

            default:
                RCFile.IniWriteValue("ERROR", "Path",Path.GetFullPath(file));
                break;
        }
```

I have links that end with case: ""
how I can add several keyname in the same section for example the section 'chrome favorites' has several keyname but in the ini file only shows one

Comment: Is the problem: you call `RCFile.IniWriteValue` multiple times, but ini-file contains just one (last?) value? See [mcve], you have to show us all relevant code as well as input, output and what you want instead.

Comment: What is doing the _RCFile.IniWriteValue_? The file structure of an ini file requires _sections_ (the part between square brackets) and each section must be unique in the file, then inside a section you could have many _keys_ (the part before the equal sign) and each key must be unique inside that section and finally the _value_ (the part after the equal sign) and here you don't have restrictions on uniqueness.

Comment: So, the answer is. You can't. Think about it, if you have multiple keys with the same name how do you retrieve a specific key from a set of identical names?

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Ini
{
    public string path;

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section,
        string key, string val, string filePath);
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
             string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal,
        int size, string filePath);


    public Ini(string INIPath)
    {
        path = INIPath;
    }

    public void IniWriteValue(string Section, string Key, string Value)
    {
        WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value, this.path);
    }

    public string IniReadValue(string Section, string Key)
    {
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
        int i = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", temp,
                                        255, this.path);
        return temp.ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps